# Does resizing of dask partition improve speed?

Tags: python, dask

I have a dask dataframe with 2700 partitions. Each partition is about of 1 mln of lines. I want to find all unique values in one of columns with `unique()` function. Will it improve speed if  I do `df.repartition` on this dataset to decrease a partitions amount and increase partition size ?

Comment: It depends on the size of the memory you have - in general each partition should fit into the memory

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "Maybe".

Performance depends on many things.  I recommend trying things out and see what works.  You may also want to read through our [Understanding Performance](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/understanding-performance.html) documentation page, which has several suggestions for how to understand and measure performance.